# Save to a PFUser using Cloud code Swift

Tags: javascript, swift, parse-platform, parse-cloud-code

I'm trying to modify PFUsers using Cloud Code.  I have just recently been introduced to JavaScript so please forgive any blatant syntax mistakes.

**Main.js**

```
Parse.Cloud.define('addWinsLosses', function(request,responce) {

    Parse.Cloud.useMasterKey();

    var winnerUserId = request.params.winnerUserId, 
        loserUserId = resquest.params.loserUserId

    var User = Parse.Object.extend('_User'),
        winner = new User({ objectId: winnerUserId });

    winner.set('wins', 1)

    winner.save(null, {
        success: function (winner) {
            response.success();
            console.log("Save ok");
        },
        error: function (error) {
            response.error(error);
            console.log("Error");
        }
    });

    var User = Parse.Object.extend('_User'),
        loser = new User({ objectId: loserUserId });

    loser.set('losses', 1)

    loser.save(null, {
        success: function (loser) {
            response.success();
            console.log("Save ok");
        },
        error: function (error) {
            response.error(error);
            console.log("Error");
        }
    });
});
```

As you can see above I am trying to send up PFUser Id strings to then modify the specific PFUsers.  I am suspecting that it is the transition from PFUser Id to PFUser pointer that is the issue here.

I'm getting this error:

```
[Error]: ReferenceError: resquest is not defined
        at main.js:10:17 (Code: 141, Version: 1.9.1)
    Optional(Error Domain=Parse Code=141 "ReferenceError: resquest is not defined
        at main.js:10:17" UserInfo={code=141, error=ReferenceError: resquest is not defined
        at main.js:10:17, temporary=0, NSLocalizedDescription=ReferenceError: resquest is not defined
        at main.js:10:17})
```

The line of code that the error is referencing is this one `winner.save(null, {`

Here is the code in my View Controller:

```
PFCloud.callFunctionInBackground("addWinsLosses", withParameters: ["winnerUserId" : (judgedGame.winner?.objectId)!, "loserUserId" : (judgedGame.winner?.objectId)!], block: { (result: AnyObject?, error: NSError?) -> Void in

                        if (error == nil) {

                        } else {
                            print(error)
                        }
                    })
                }
```

One other detail that I should mention is that I subclassed the PFUser which I don't believe should make a difference but I'm throwing that out there just in case.

**What is the issue with my code?**

Comment: It clearly says that `resquest` is not defined because you misspelt `request` on line number 10 !!

Comment: Thank you for the help, must have been brain dead after all that Thanksgiving food.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've misspelled `response` as `responce` in your funciton defnition.

Also, you're redefining the `User` variable on line 22, but that won't cause a crash.

Comment: I corrected both typos which made the error go away.  The code is working however my "winner" PFUser is getting both a win and a loss instead of just getting a win; I'm suspecting it's the redefining of the `User`.  How can I create a separate instance of a PFUser so my loser can get his loss?  I tried merely renaming but that doesn't work.

Comment: Your code looks fine now... Could you log the values of the ids?

Comment: And by calling 'response.success()' in your completion block for the first save, you're going to return early if the save finishes quickly. I would highly recommend learning promises for writing asynchronous code.

Comment: Perhaps the easy way to fix both the issue I'm facing and the `response.success()` is merely make another function.  But to answer your previous question, yes, the Ids are different so I do believe the issue is with this line `var User = Parse.Object.extend('_User'),`.

Comment: UPDATE: Even using two different functions produces the same result of the "winner" PFObject getting both a win and a loss.

Comment: [I can help you in this chat.](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/96614/parse-help)